# Problem while roaming between AP's

Tags: wireless, access-point

## **The problem**

Roaming from the RT-AC68U (we can’t roam between the WLR-4004, which may won’t work too) to the Archer C5 doesn’t work properly, but backwards it works properly.

In this case, we have to wait for a few minutes and restart Wi-Fi on the roaming phone/notebook (which may not be required, but this seems to speed it up). On my Android phone, I won’t get an IP address or a connection to the rest of the network. I’m only able to ping to the Archer C5 and not the RT-AC68U or Google’s DNS when this happens.

## **Things tried**

Removing the switch between the RT-AC68U and the Archer C5: Didn’t seems to effect anything, still the same problem as explained above.

## **Network configuration**

- Ground floor: Asus RT-AC68U (our main router)
- 2th floor (attic): TP-Link Archer C5 (configured as AP, no DHCP/NAT)
- Garden: Sitecom WLR-4004 (configured as AP, no DHCP/NAT)

There is 1 unmanaged switch (TP-link TL-SG108) between the RT-AC68U and the Archer C5.

All AP’s are configured to use a separate channel (1, 6, 11), with the same SSID’s.

## **Question**

Why can't I roam from RT-AC68U to the Archer C5 and what/where could be the problem?

Comment: Problem fixed by installing DD-WRT on the Archer C5. Still wonder why I had this issue with the stock firmware, any logic explanation for this?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network, or on [su] for a personal network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In this case, we have to wait for a few minutes and restart Wi-Fi on the roaming phone/notebook (which may not be required, but this seems to speed it up). On my Android phone, I won’t get an IP address or a connection to the rest of the network. I’m only able to ping to the Archer C5 and not the RT-AC68U or Google’s DNS when this happens.

It looks like a problem related to ARP table. The AP associates you with the previous path to reach you and does not refresh the ARP table until after a while.
That is why the problem is resolved over time or restarting the device.